# Expanding when one has command substitution

Tags: linux, bash

I have to echo an output of a command substitution concatenated with string. The string to be prepended is in fact the string of pathname. The need for use of absolute path together with filename arises due to filename containing special character,`-`, at the beginning of it. I've come up with a draft that only works as planned for the first line of output. How do I expand it to other lines as well?

The example scenario is as provided below.

Inside `/tmp` directory the files are:

```
-foo 1.txt
-bar 1.txt
```

Command and the output is:

```
$ echo "$PWD/$(ls | grep "^-")"
/tmp/-bar 1.txt
-foo 1.txt
```

While I want it to be like

```
/tmp/-bar 1.txt
/tmp/-foo 1.txt
```

I read about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Brace_expansion) brace expansion feature but I'm not sure if it works for variables, or command substitution for that matter, as stated [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace). I also want the separate lines for each files and the filename words unsplitted, which is suggested at when the brace expansion is carried out. (Honestly, I don't understand much of the literature about the features such as brace expansion!)

Also, are there other more convenient ways to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "absolute paths"? Yours aren't relative. Also, what do you want to do with these filenames? How would you do it if they would *not* start with `-`?

Comment: Yes, I do  mean absolute paths. I'll re-edit.

Comment: Relative pathname would also serve the need, however. Shall the filenames _not_ start with a `-`, I would have simply piped the ls to grep.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do and how the `-` keep you from doing it.

Comment: I just want the filenames with full path shown on separate lines for each filename. This is to pass it as a list of filenames in the FILE argument of pdfgrep command in particular.

Comment: The filename strings containing `-` at start is parsed with special meaning, if not the absolute/relative path is served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you're asking, getting a list of full paths for files starting with `-`, you can use [`readlink`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#readlink-invocation):

```
$ readlink -f ./-*
/tmp/-bar 1.pdf
/tmp/-foo 1.pdf
```

However, to do directly what you mentioned in comments (using filenames starting with `-` as arguments for `pdfgrep`), you can take advantage of the [common convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Common-options) that `--` marks the end of options, so everything after it is recognized as a filename:

```
pdfgrep 'pattern' -- -*
```

See also [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) (Guideline 10):

> The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `-` character.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ls` *at all*. You can use a glob, and your loop can be implicit

```
$ printf '%s\n' /tmp/-*
/tmp/-foo 1.txt
/tmp/-bar 1.txt
```

or explicit

```
$ for f in /tmp/-*; do echo "$f"; done
/tmp/-foo 1.txt
/tmp/-bar 1.txt
```

Comment: Great! that you mention the implicit way. There must be a typo in the third line of explicit statement way (misses a slash).

Comment: Anyway, Now my concern is how would I go about when I have more elaborate construct to define a file pattern (with grep like patterns)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
for f in /tmp/-*
do
   echo $f
done
```

Comment: `echo "$f"`, maybe? The file names contain spaces, and unquoted expansion might lead to surprising results.